# JQuery Full Page JS

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js with PHP. I have this code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
anchors: ['homepage', 'aboutmepage'],
menu: '#menu',
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
    ALERT anchors[1] here!

    // changeNav(nextIndex);
}}
```

I need to alert the content of anchors based on an index. I don't know how. I've tried `$('anchors')[0]` but it did not work. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
    //anchor of the leaving section
    alert( $(this).attr('data-anchor') );

   //anchor of the destination section
   alert( $('.fp-section').eq(nextIndex - 1 ).attr('data-anchor') );
}
```